# Can't report load for the metrics in Actors Service

Tags: azure-service-fabric

There is a nice feature in Service Fabric that allows each service object to update its own load during runtime. Dynamic load reports allow replicas or instances to adjust their allocation/reported load of metrics over their lifetime. 
Here is how I can do this within a service:

```
this.Partition.ReportLoad(new List<LoadMetric> { new LoadMetric("MemoryInMb", 1234)});
```

The problem is that Partition is a protected property that is declared in StatefulServiceBase, so it's available in ActorService but not in Actor. I mean, I can't do Actor.ActorService.Partition.ReportLoad(...). I do see a workaround where I could create my custom actor service class and make this property public, but I'm wondering if it makes sense and was there any particular reason to not being able to report the load in Actors?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ActorService does derive from StatefulServiceBase. You should be good to go.

See this: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.servicefabric.actors.runtime.actorservice?redirectedfrom=MSDN#microsoft_servicefabric_actors_runtime_actorservice

---

edit:
What load metric do you have that's specific to one Actor instance?

Actors usually have a limited lifespan. Load reporting is a periodic process. Those two don't really combine well. Yes, you could use `ActorReminders`, but why use them when you have an `ActorService` that can do the same thing without the limitations?

Comment: Sorry for the confusion, I've edited the question. So yeah, I can report the load from the ActorService, but not from the Actor itself, merely because Actor 'uses' ActorService but is not derived from it.

Comment: I need to run some tasks across the cluster based on a regular schedule. That's the reason I'm so interested about Actors and Reminders. As for metrics, I was thinking to leverage them to let the Fabric know that Actors may launch some heavy processes, so even though they are lightweight on their own, the work they spawn not so much. So in my sick mind, having Actors reporting metrics would allow Fabric to balance them better.

Comment: You could create a delegate or interface that encapsulates the ReportLoad method of the ```ActorService``` and pass that to the ctor of your Actor.

Comment: Yeah, delegate and interface are all good ways to get access to Partition property. The question is, does anybody know if it makes any difference for the Fabric? I mean, would I be able to alter how Fabric distributes actors this way? Or it's completely worthless and I should forget about it?

Comment: You report load on the level of partition, an Actor instance is tied to a partition by its ActorId. So no you can't influence Actor distribution this way.

Comment: Ok, makes sense. But if I try to create a new actor with a random id, would the Fabric try to have it created in the partition with the least load based on the metrics that I fed the Fabric with? Or it's completely random and depends on the generated id of the Actor?

Comment: Every ActorId is hashed to an Int64, which is why the actor service must use an Int64 partitioning scheme with the full Int64 key range. However, custom ID values can be used for an ActorID, including GUIDs, strings, and Int64s. When using GUIDs and strings, the values are hashed to an Int64. However, when explicitly providing an Int64 to an ActorId, the Int64 will map directly to a partition without further hashing. This can be used to control which partition actors are placed in.

Comment: I'll rephrase the question - is there a way to ask the Fabric to create a new actor in the least loaded partition w/o being responsible for Actor ID? Let's say I have 5 partitions distrubuted across 5 nodes, and each node has one primary instance running on it. The first node uses the most amount of the resources and I'd like to create an actor on any node but the first one. I know that I can control which partition Actor will be placed in, but I would also need to do extra work to identify the least loaded node in the code... Can I just create an actor and leave the rest for the Fabric?